# Div select dropdown menu jquery toggle and option

Tags: jquery, css, select, toggle

I'm trying to make my dropdown menu work in jquery, but for some reason the .select div keeps fading away with this script when it loads.

```
<div class="select">Select your option</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
        <li>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I've got this script here -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select").toggle(function () {
        $(".dropdown").fadeIn("slow");
    },

    function () {
        $(".dropdown").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Also - I'm trying to figure out how would I change the content of .select based on what they click from .dropdown ? Or what is the most efficient way?

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: I have jquery version 1.10.2

Comment: .toggle function is depreciated in version 1.8 so after that version it can not be used.See [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[**fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f29m2/1/)

Read

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) `Deprecated > Deprecated 1.8` and removed inn after `1.9`.So you can not use it with `1.10`

[Deprecated Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select").click(function () {
        $(".dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
    });

    $('.dropdown li').click(function () {
        $(".select").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

As, `.toggle(function, function, ... )` is removed in [jQuery 1.9 upgrade release](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f29m2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, must be too tired to not think of this ha!